# Uploading texture is very slow in OpenGL

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, upload, textures

I have a list of images that I want to display, using OpenGL textures (Android NDK/SDK). I have put the image data into an array to be used by `glTexImage2D`. I initialized the variables and ran `glDeleteTextures(1, &hedy);` for uploading and displaying each image.

Everything is OK but it works slowly (2.5ms for loading a texture). How can I improve the app's performance?
Can I upload the image data into GPU memory once and use it many times?
Do you have any solution or recommendation to display images at high speed?

```
glGenTextures(1, &hedy);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hedy);  
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);  
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: Do the current process only once for all the textures when you start your application and when you need to call the image simply bind the texture by  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hedy) , delete the images only when you exit application.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It worked and improved my performance and I have 2.15 ms instead of 2.5 ms. But I am looking for 16.8ms for each frame. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Simply binding a texture should be much faster than 2.15 ms , on my system binding a 512 X 512 image (glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hedy) ) Takes only 3500 nanoseconds.Which graphics card are you using ?

Comment: Displaying a 512*512 image takes 1.9 milliseconds and is more than 500 times slower than you. Could you please send me a source code or give me a link to a code that just displays an image to compare it with my code? my device is: NOKIA HMD global TA-1053 CPU Octa-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A53 GPU Adreno 505
I have noticed that the 80% of wasting time is about compiling and binding shaders. Is it possible to compile the shader one time and use it many times?

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. Displaying a 512*512 image with some shader operations takes 200 microseconds and I have reached more than 60 FPS.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to Generate a Texture once.

```
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Now we can keep using texture with the call

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

The same goes for shaders we need to compile them only once .

```
Shader loadShaderFromFile(const GLchar *vShaderFile, const GLchar *fShaderFile, const GLchar *gShaderFile)
{
    // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::string geometryCode;
    try
    {
        // Open files
        std::ifstream vertexShaderFile(vShaderFile);
        std::ifstream fragmentShaderFile(fShaderFile);
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        // Read file's buffer contents into streams
        vShaderStream << vertexShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fShaderStream << fragmentShaderFile.rdbuf();
        // close file handlers
        vertexShaderFile.close();
        fragmentShaderFile.close();
        // Convert stream into string
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        // If geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
        if (gShaderFile != nullptr)
        {
            std::ifstream geometryShaderFile(gShaderFile);
            std::stringstream gShaderStream;
            gShaderStream << geometryShaderFile.rdbuf();
            geometryShaderFile.close();
            geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        QMessageBox message;
        message.setText("ERROR::SHADER: Failed to read shader files");
        message.exec();

    }
    const GLchar *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const GLchar *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
    const GLchar *gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
    // 2. Now create shader object from source code
    Shader shader;
    shader.Compile(vShaderCode, fShaderCode, gShaderFile != nullptr ? gShaderCode : nullptr);
    return shader;
}
```

Now you can keep bind this shader when you need it with this call.

```
glUseProgram(ShaderId);
```

Generate all the textures and Compile the shaders when your application initializes and than keep using them.